# Sequence of projections on a sequence in Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

I need help with the following related to my research. Let $\{e_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis for a Hilbert space $H$. Let $V_n:= \text{span}\{e_1, e_2, \ldots , e_n\} \subset H$, and let $P_n: H \to V_n$ be the orthogonal projection given by $P_n x:= \sum_{j=1}^n \langle x, e_j \rangle e_j$ for $x\in H$. In such case, I know that $\|P_n x - x\|_H \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

**My problem is this:** Let $x_n \in H$. Is it true in general that $\|P_n x_n - x_n\|_H \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ ?

Here I don't have any uniform bound on $\|x_n\|_H$. If the above statement is not correct, what condition(s) should I impose in addition?

I am also happy if $\|P_n x_n - x_n\|_H $ is merely bounded by some constant independent of $n$ for large enough $n$ (if that's at all possible under certain cases).

Comment: sorry I meant $x_n$ is a sequence in $H$, not in $V_n$.

Comment: Take $x_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}e_i$.

Comment: Take $x_n=ne_{n+1}.$ More generally if $P_ny_n-y_n\neq 0$ by taking $x_n=\alpha_ny_n$ you can make the norm arbitrary large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is not true. Counterexamples include $x_n= ne_{n+1}$ as suggested in the comments.